# How to calculate this determinant of a $2\times 2$matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, math-software

This matrix arises from a homework problem which our professor gave.

We need to find the determinant of this matrix.

Does there exist any simple way to find the determinant of this matrix?

> $\begin{pmatrix}
>   x-pq-p+3-(q-1)(\frac{x+2-n}{x-n+2-l}) && (1-p)(2+\frac{l}{x-n+2-l})\\
>   (1-q)(2+\frac{l}{x-n+2-l}) && x-pq-q+3-(p-1)(\frac{x+2-n}{x-n+2-l})
>   \end{pmatrix}$

Here $n=pq$ and $l=\phi(n)+1$.

Is there any software which can calculate this large determinant?

One of my friends got $x-n+2-l$ as a factor of this determinant.

Is there any simple way to calculate this determinant?

I am stuck.

**My try**:

$R_1\to R_1-R_2$ gives

$\begin{pmatrix}
  x-pq-p+q+2 && -x+pq+q-p-2\\
  (1-q)(2+\frac{l}{x-n+2-l}) && x-pq-q+3-(p-1)(\frac{x+2-n}{x-n+2-l})
  \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, it is very simple, just $ad-bc$ for a $2\times 2$-matrix with entries $a,b,c,d$. Do you want to see it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think the question is about how to make this particular calculation less messy.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Exactly where did you get stuck? Why are you mentioning the eigenvalue? It's the matrix that has eigenvalues, but not the determinant, but anyway the mention of eigenvalue makes me wonder if you've not presented the complete problem.

Comment: @J.G.;you are correct thank you . there are people here who deliberately make fun of others

Comment: @skyking; I have added my work

Comment: @J.G.; added my work

Comment: Just asking, but are $p, q$ primes? Is $\phi$ the Euler $\phi$ function?

Comment: @ancientmathematician; yes they are

Comment: I think you should edit to make that clear in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to see my computation, I obtain the following determinant
by a direct computation and a further factorisation:
$$
\det(A)=\frac{f(p,q,x)}{((2q - 1)p - (q + x))^2},
$$

where

$$
f(p,q,x)=(2p^2q^2 + 2p^2q + 2pq^2 - 3pqx - 14pq - px + 2p - qx + 2q + x^2 + 6x + 4)(2pq - p - q - x)(pq - x - 2)
$$
Here I have substituted $n=pq$ and $l=\phi(n)+1=(p-1)(q-1)+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Call your matrix $M$ and let $s=x+2-n$. Then
\begin{aligned}
M&=\pmatrix{
x-pq-p+3-(q-1)(\frac{x+2-n}{x-n+2-l}) &(1-p)(2+\frac{l}{x-n+2-l})\\
(1-q)(2+\frac{l}{x-n+2-l}) &x-pq-q+3-(p-1)(\frac{x+2-n}{x-n+2-l})}\\
&=\pmatrix{x-pq-p+3 &1-p\\ 1-q &x-pq-q+3}
+\frac{x+2-n}{x+2-n-l}\pmatrix{1-q&1-p\\ 1-q&1-p}\\
&=sI+\pmatrix{1-p&1-p\\ 1-q&1-q}
+\frac{s}{s-l}\pmatrix{1-q&1-p\\ 1-q&1-p}.
\end{aligned}
(The second equality above is borrowed from J.G.'s answer.)

If $l=2s$, then $\dfrac{s}{s-l}=-1$. Hence
$$
M=\pmatrix{s+q-p&0\\ 0&s+p-q}
$$
and
$$
\det(M)=s^2-(p-q)^2.
$$
If $l\ne2s$, let $t=\dfrac{s-l}{2s-l},\ p'=\dfrac{1-p}{t}$ and $q'=\dfrac{1-q}{t}$. Then
$$
M=\pmatrix{s+tp'+(1-t)q'&p'\\ q'&s+tq'+(1-t)p'}
$$
and hence
$$
\det(M)=\left(s+tp'+(1-t)q'\right)\left(s+tq'+(1-t)p'\right)-p'q'.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It helps to rewrite your matrix as $A+B$ with$$A:=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
x-pq-p+3 & 1-p\\
1-q & x-pq-q+3
\end{array}\right),\,B:=\frac{x+2-n}{x+2-n-l}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1-q & 1-p\\
1-q & 1-p
\end{array}\right).$$Write $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{array}\right),\,B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e & g\\
f & h
\end{array}\right)$ so$$\begin{align}\det\left(A+B\right)&=\det A+\det B+\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & g\\
b & h
\end{array}\right)+\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e & c\\
f & d
\end{array}\right)\\&=\left(x-pq+3\right)^{2}-\left(p+q\right)\left(x-pq+3\right)-1+p+q\\&+\frac{x+2-n}{x+2-n-l}\left[\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}
x-pq-p+3 & 1-p\\
1-q & 1-p
\end{array}\right)+\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1-q & 1-p\\
1-q & x-pq-q+3
\end{array}\right)\right]\\&=\left(x-pq+3\right)^{2}-\left(p+q\right)\left(x-pq+3\right)-1+p+q\\&+\frac{x+2-n}{x+2-n-l}\left[\left(x-\left(p-1\right)\left(q+1\right)+1\right)\left(1-p\right)+\left(x-\left(p+1\right)\left(q-1\right)+1\right)\left(1-q\right)\right]\\&=\left(x-pq+3\right)^{2}-\left(p+q\right)\left(x-pq+3\right)-1+p+q\\&+\frac{x+2-n}{x+2-n-l}\left[\left(1+x\right)\left(2-p-q\right)+\left(p-1\right)^{2}\left(q+1\right)+\left(p+1\right)\left(q-1\right)^{2}\right].\end{align}$$

Comment: Is it possible to factor out $x-n+2-l$ from here?